# Getting cookie value in another web page with PHP and JSP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a web-based portal where we have 2 types of login pages depending on the end user, admin and associate. Anyone who wants to log in the web-based portal first has to enter his type (i.e. end user, admin, associate) then he has to give his id and password in the next page.

Now there are several users and associates. I want that any user or associate should not be able to change the database value of other users or associates. So I am trying to store the user ID in the login page by using the `setcookie` function. I want to access that value in other pages, where the user can see what are the files assigned to their name.

I am trying to show those files from the database using the MySQL query in another web page.

```
$result = mysql_query("select file_name from File where
  user_name = '$user_name';");
```

But I am not getting the cookie value at '$user_id'

I used this code:

```
<?php
//$mycookie = $_COOKIE["cookie_user_name"];
if (isset( $mycookie))
  print "<p>The value in cookie - $mycookie</p>";
else
  print "<p>There is no value in cookie.</p>";
?>
```

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us how you use `setcookie`?

Comment: It is not a good idea to store login info in a cookie. The user would be able to change it to anything he wants. You could (should) use sessions for that.

Comment: Maybe you are serving pages on different domains? This way cookies won't work.

Comment: @PLB i have set my cookie at login page like this..             $result2 = mysql_query("select user_name from associate where user_id='$user_id';");

setcookie("cookie_user_name", $result2);

Comment: @germi thanks germi but i have already used session variable to differentiate between 3 kind of user that is enduser, associate, and admin. that is why i can not use it for the second time... then the other web pages will become unavailable to other user... i mean i tried this bt may b there would something other way round... can you give me details about the session variable...

Comment: @fliespl i am using a single domain. i am using wamp server and there is only localhost... nothing else is there...

Comment: @sayantanbagchi You are setting resource instead of string to your cookie
you are missing mysql_fetch_row...

Comment: @sayantanbagchi add `time()+60 //60 represents 60 minutes` as third parameter in `setcookie`.

Comment: @fliespl i used mysql_fetch_row but still it is showing there is now value in cookie. remember i am setting the cookie at login page and trying to get the at another webpage file_alloted.php

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `isset($mycookie)` - but `$mycookie` will always be set because you set it just one line earlier.

You need to check if `$_COOKIE["cookie_user_name"]` is set. (I suggest using the `empty()` function for this instead of `isset()`.)

For a more complete answer include the code with `setcookie`.

Just a gentle suggestion: You are not qualified to be writing security code, you are still a novice. Wait until you have more experience before trying to write security code.

Comment: thanks @ariel now i have corrected it. i have deleted that line... now it is only there in log in page like this                                                                                                  $result2 = mysql_query("select user_name from associate where user_id='$user_id';");

setcookie("cookie_user_name", $result2);

Comment: thanks for suggestion... but how would i get experienced if i dont try to write this security code...

Comment: is there something related with cookies and header??

Comment: @sayantanbagchi First you should gain lots of experience writing regular code for PHP, only then should you try to write security code.

Comment: @sayantanbagchi I'm sorry that I was not able to help you with your code but you are just not giving us enough information. The little code snippet is not enough to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: its ok... i have figured it out...  thank you so much for your kind attention... thank you...